# Autotools Home Directory

Tags: linux, autotools

I want my program to create files at run-time (log files and such), so it needs to know the home directory of the user, or else he/she would have to run the program as root every time (to create the files in directories like /var).

Is there some way to add a -D define in the Makefile.am that is automatically filled with the home directory? For instance I already have `AM_CPPFLAGS=-DDATADIR='"$(datadir)"'` to define the data directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any macro or built-in path in Autotools, that represent user's home directory, you can obtain it at runtime using (for example) [environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).

BTW. for logging I recommend [syslog()](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog.html#Syslog) .

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the HOME environment variable for your program instead?